# Wrong IsAlive() behaviour in Thread

Tags: java, multithreading

I have just seen problem in my below code in isAlive method , it will return false even thread.start() method has been called, even i also tried to add some sleep in main thread as well as my thread object but still it gives same behavior.

```
public class ThreadBehaviour implements Runnable {
    private Thread t;

    ThreadBehaviour() {
        t = new Thread();
        t.setName("hello");

    }

    public void start() throws InterruptedException {
        if (!t.isAlive()) {
            t.start();

            //Thread.currentThread().sleep(1000L);
            //t.sleep(3000l);
            System.out.println(t.getName() + " Running....." + t.isAlive());// why is Alive is false here?
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
        ThreadBehaviour myThread = new ThreadBehaviour();

        myThread.start();

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        t.run();

    }

}
```

Comment: Honestly, I am not quite sure about what you are trying to do here

Comment: I just want to clear concept regarding isAlive method, my question is in my start method even i write t.start then why isAlive is return false ?

Comment: To test `isAlive`, create a separate class that implements `Runnable` and use it to create and start a thread in your main class. In your Runable's `run()`, use `sleep` and a loop. In your main, check i the thread is alive

Comment: You have created a `Thread` which doesn't do anything so you would have trouble catching it alive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your Thread that you made does nothing, so it instantly finishes and dies.

Consider this:

```
t = new Thread(() -> {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println("I'm running...");
    }
});
```

and try again.

Answer (score 1):

Read the java doc
isAlive();

- Tests if this thread is alive. A thread is alive if it has been
  started and has not yet died.

You only instantiate in constructor without started. So the thread is not started.